# How to retrieve data from Firebase to table chat?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried from doc Firebase, but where should I display the table chat? What I've tried so far:

```
Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl: @"https://simplechatapps.firebaseio.com"];
[[[ref queryOrderedByChild:@"message"] queryLimitedToLast:1] observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    NSArray *message = snapshot.value[@"message"];
    NSLog(@"%@",message);


}];
```

Here's what the data looks like

```
--17
 --chat
   -Kal21gac2x2Za6q-Yq6
       from: "13"
       message: "hallo"
       sender: "c52fb228be35675a"
       time: "1484734081595"
       to:  "0"
```

Note : 17 is chat room

ultimately ZHCHAT I use to help me in completing my application.https://github.com/zhuozhuo/ZHChat
but I get a deadlock in retrieving data from firebase

Comment: Check what is the type of message, add `NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromClass([message class]));`

Comment: @iphonic the type is NSCFString